# How to show search result not found message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator, conditional-rendering

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function DataApi({ searchTerm }) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(res => {
        setUsers(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
        setLoading(true);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        setError('Error retrieving data');
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {
          !loading ?
          <h1>...Loading</h1>
          :
          users.length > 0 && users.filter((item) => 
            (searchTerm === '') ?  item :
            (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())) ? item :
            // <h1>search result not found</h1>
            null
          ).map((item) => {
          return (
          <ul key={item.id}>
            <li>Name: {item.id}</li>
            <li>Title: {item.title}</li>
            <li>Body: {item.body}</li>
          </ul>
            )}
            )
          }
          {
            error ? <h1>{error}</h1> : null
          }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DataApi;
```

I have made a search field in which user can search the name of the person. If user does not get the searched name then there should be a message come that `search result not found`. I tried to implement it using if-else (ternary operator) & put the message into else part but it is not working. When I put `null` instead of `search result not found` then it works perfectly but I am not able to show the message then. But if I put `search result not found` instead of `null` then nothing works, not even filter functionality. Can you guys please help me? Thank you in advancve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check the length of user and move the filter method to the useEffect and show a message

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function DataApi({ searchTerm }) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [searchTermTest, setsearchTermTest] = useState();

  function handleChange(event) {
    setsearchTermTest(event.target.value);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => {
        const data = res.data;
        const filteredData = data.filter((dat) =>
          dat.title.includes(searchTermTest === undefined ? "" : searchTermTest)
        );
        setUsers(filteredData);
        setLoading(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("errr", error);
        setError("Error retrieving data");
      });
  }, [searchTermTest]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
      <div>
        {!loading ? (
          <h1>...Loading</h1>
        ) : (
          users.length > 0 &&
          users.map((item) => {
            return (
              <ul key={item.id}>
                <li>Name: {item.id}</li>
                <li>Title: {item.title}</li>
                <li>Body: {item.body}</li>
              </ul>
            );
          })
        )}
        {users.length === 0 && loading ? <h1>search result not found</h1> : ""}
        {error ? <h1>{error}</h1> : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DataApi;
```

```
        {users.length === 0 && loading ? <h1>search result not found</h1> : ""}
```

I have made it in codesandbox

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-sammet-fcrhu?file=/src/App.js) link here

Comment: Thank you for your response but your answer is not meet my requirements. I already have data shown on the screen. On top, there is a search box. Whenever a user search data, below data will automatically be filtered.

Comment: please check the codesandbox to see the updated code. I hope this will solve your issue

Comment: I checked your codesandbox link. But unfortunately it is not working as per my expectation. Can you please do something different. Thank you for your valuable time & response.

Comment: It was easy to modify to make it same as your requirement which you could have done. Anyways i have updated it to meet exactly as you asked in the post

Comment: Thank you for fixing this but can you please tell me the use of line no. 48 in codesandbox link?

Comment: It checks the length of users array and if its 0, it means the filtered data has no results, and then it will show the error message as you want

Comment: There is one issue with your code. The `search result not found` is coming along with `Loading...` text when the page loads. You can check it on your codesandbox. Can you please fix this?

Comment: Done. Just add the loading condition also then it will be ok

Comment: Thanks for fixing the issue. It is working fine now. But can you please do me one more favor? Can you please add the functionality like though user enters the input in UPPERCASE then also it shows the result?

Comment: yes it is possible by converting the passed data and data in array to upper case and comparing. I have updated the code. Please mark as answer and upvote if i solved the issue

Comment: Thank you so much, man!!! Your solution meets my requirement exactly. I have upvote your answer. Please check.

Comment: Glad i could help!! Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

In `Array.filter()` method you need to return `true/false` value, that's how it [works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Modified the code and added the `renderUser` function to take care of user data filter.

> DataApi function

```
function DataApi({ searchTerm }) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [searchTermTest, setsearchTermTest] = useState();

  function handleChange(event) {
    setsearchTermTest(event.target.value);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => {
        const data = res.data;
        const filteredData = data.filter((dat) =>
          dat.title.includes(searchTermTest === undefined ? "" : searchTermTest)
        );
        setUsers(filteredData);
        setLoading(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("errr", error);
        setError("Error retrieving data");
      });
  }, [searchTermTest]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
      <div>
        {!loading ? (
          <h1>...Loading</h1>
        ) : (
          users.length > 0 && renderUsers(users, searchTerm) // updated here...
        )}
        {error ? <h1>{error}</h1> : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> renderUsers function

```
const renderUsers = (users, searchTerm) => {
  const filteredUsers = users.filter((item) => {
    console.log(item.title);
    return searchTerm === ""
      ? true
      : item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())
      ? true
      : false;
  });
  return filteredUsers.length > 0 ? (
    filteredUsers.map((item) => {
      return (
        <ul key={item.id}>
          <li>Name: {item.id}</li>
          <li>Title: {item.title}</li>
          <li>Body: {item.body}</li>
        </ul>
      );
    })
  ) : (
    <h1>search result not found</h1>
  );
};

export default DataApi;
```